# Unable to load Maps in Android (ClassDefNotFoundError)

Tags: android, maps

I am trying to make a simple Android project using Google Maps, however, I can't seem to get it past a simple error

This is the source code:

```
package mapa.pack.mapamerodeador;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class ActividadPrincipal extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.seccion_1);
    }
}
```

Also, this is the layout:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/fondo_pag1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView 
                      android:id="@+id/titulo_pag1"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                      android:text="@string/pag1"
                      android:textSize="23sp"
                      android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <fragment
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:id="@+id/mapa"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/titulo_pag1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonUno" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonUno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@color/gris"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="@string/link_pag_2" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and last but not least, the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mapa.pack.mapamerodeador"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<permission
    android:name="mapa.pack.merodeador.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="mapa.pack.merodeador.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >    

    <uses-library 
        android:required="true"
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="mapa.pack.mapamerodeador.ActividadPrincipal"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
        android:name="mapa.pack.mapamerodeador.Autores" />

    <activity 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:name="mapa.pack.mapamerodeador.Ajustes" />

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I'm aware that there are activities in the manifest that I haven't referred to in the code, but it's because not even those 2 lines seem to work, so I commented the rest. When I try to execute it I get a **"java.lang.NoClasDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable at com.google.gms.maps.GoogleMapsOptions.createFromAttributes(UnknownSource)"**
Does anybody know what could be the problem? Thanks!! =)

EDIT: If I comment the < fragment> in the XML, then it won't show anything, but at least it doesn't crash, so I figure whatever is wrong, is in there, is there any way to work around it?

Comment: Do you have the google play library installed?

Comment: I'm kind of new to this, so I'm not sure what you mean by "Installed",  if I open the "SDK Manager" in the "Extras" folder there is one option (Google Play Services) and it is currently Installed, yes. I'm not sure this is what you mean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems in your manifest file:

**1.** While you package name is:

```
package="mapa.pack.mapamerodeador"
```

in the google maps perrmission you are setting `mapa.pack.merodeador`:

```
<permission
android:name="mapa.pack.merodeador.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

The have to be identical.

**2.** Rmove this code:

```
 <uses-library 
    android:required="true"
    android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

It's a `Google Map API V1` permission, and not needed in `Google Map API V2`.

**3.** But by your error my guess would be is that you are not referencing the `google-play-services` library correctly. check the first three steps of this blog post I wrote and make sure you make all the steps right:

[Google Map API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: Wow, awesome, thanks a lot, I didn't even notice that... all those tutorials kinda confused me, however, I encountered a problem when importing the library, I did all the steps and the green tick shows, but as soon as I close the window it just turns into a big ugly red cross and no matter what I do it always happens. Do you know what could be causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: try to move this file to a location where it's path would be shorter, and then try to reference it again.

Comment: did you had to move the file in order to make the referencing work correctly?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I did that the map started showing just fine... =)

Answer (score 0):

Emulator doesnt show the new Google Map api v2. You need to have a real device to test it.

Comment: Yes, but not only does it not show, it actually crashes... I've tried on a device and it doesn't seem to work either. Although I made a significant discovery, I will edit my question.